# ajax not working while returning a String value

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

I have written following jquery code in one of my Java project.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#searchBid').click(function(){
        alert("reached ajax");
        $.ajax({
            url: "/fetchbookingnumber",
            data: {id:$('#conBid').val()},
            timeout: 10000,
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend:function(jqXHR, options) {
                if($('#conBid').val()==''){
                    alert("Please enter a BookingID");  
                } 
                return false;
            }
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert("The ajax call failed");
        }).done(function(resp, textStatus, jqXHR){
            $('#conBno').val(resp);
        });
    });
});
```

The value that is being returned by database is a varchar. In my Java server I have stored the value in String. The problem I am facing is that as far as the returned value is a number (numeral) the ajax work but if the string returned is alphanumeric the ajax fails and .fail method is called.
I guess the cause behind this is

```
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
```

How should I alter the code to make the ajax work in both the cases. Please some one lend a hand.

Comment: Maybe server isn't returning valid JSON notation object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you really recieving JSON data ?

If it is a simple String set it to:-

`DataType: "text"`

Or like mentioned in comments send a proper JSON from the server

Comment: Or better, returns valid JSON from server ;)

Comment: Yes thats the problem i think, user is setting `DataType: "json"` and receiving random string data(not json) :)

Comment: @ Mustafa Sabir : Thanks buddy..U all got it right for me..I was not sending a valid json always. But instead of "text/plain" it is just "text" that will work for such a case.

Comment: Welcome :). oh yes checked the documentation its `text` for ajax datatype . Also please mark as answer if proved helful ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line `dataType: "json",`, it means that the server is going to send a json string as the response. Any other response will result in an error, with the exception of json encoded javascript primatives. e.g. a numeric value (5, 5.9, 0x5f, 5e2, etc), null, a string ("string", "also a string", etc) notice the quotes around the text. This is because many json parses are lenient and accept these primitives.
If you set a return type you should return that type.

Comment: I have tried replacing data type with "text/plain" instead of "json". It has resulted in more trouble for me. Now the ajax call is failing even in case of numeral data returned by server.